# paypal express checkout on REST api (C# lib)

Tags: paypal, express-checkout, paypal-rest-sdk

I dont get the idea. If Classic api have DoExpressCheckout methods... what Rest API have for it?
On that image we have the way how it should work for classic way
[image]

So for my case Express Checkout steps are:
1) Customer put items in cart and click on PayPal checkout button
I run

```
var payment = new PayPal.Api.Payment();
var createdPayment = payment.Create(apiContext);
```

so make the payment and redirect customer to paypal site

2) Customer go thu the paypal process and return back to my site. From his pay pal transaction I should get Shipment address and his email (without submit that payment!) and based on his shipment address calculate shipment cost

3) After customer select shipment method I need update his transaction (add shipment cost) and only then sumbit it.

So the questions here

1) how to get payment (transaction) info with C# lib based on paymentId (like PAY-21A17783AU475540MKYGAM5Q) because PayPal.Api.Payment() have methods only Creare, Execute and Update?

2) How to Update current transaction (add some new data like shipment cost) and then submit it?

PS. In the documents a lot of mess and a lot of people dont understand how they should use that api properly.

Duke

Answer (score 1):

Based on your post, you'd create an [`Order`](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Samples/Source/OrderSample.aspx.cs) - strongly suggest you use their library in this link (it includes samples, should get you going quickly, is very well maintained, and the maintainers are great/responsive)

1. [Create it](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Samples/Source/OrderSample.aspx.cs#l84) - this would map to classic `SetExpressCheckout`
2. [Redirect to Paypal](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Samples/Source/OrderSample.aspx.cs#l98) to obtain user approval. The redirect URL is part of the response (no longer just a token)
3. if the user "approves", Paypal redirects back just like in classic

   - you'll see this handled in the sample in the [`else` block](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Samples/Source/OrderSample.aspx.cs#L104)
   - just like in classic [`PayerID`](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Samples/Source/OrderSample.aspx.cs#L26) is in the querystring
4. [Execute](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Samples/Source/OrderSample.aspx.cs#L125) the payment

   - the response will contain the data you need as you will see in the lines below the execute statement, so this maps to `GetExpressCheckoutDetails`
   - you will also see your options on what to do next (Auth, Capture, etc.) in the commented lines. These would map to "finalizing" the payment
   - you can "adjust" for shipping/tax in the above after obtaining the details and will have same rules as classic IINM as far as the maximum additional amount you can add - [115% not to exceed $75](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/authcapture/))

If you have a sandbox account, I have a debug page [here](http://code.edchavez.com/Pay/PayPal) that shows the data io that maybe helpful.

*Note that I'm only partially capturing (`"is_final_capture": false`) so if you check your sandbox (buyer) account, the total charged wouldn't be the full amount*

Hth..